# Error in setting up cassandra cluster on gcp instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cassandra

I am trying to set up a cassandra cluster on GCP instances and trying to communicate with them through my laptop.

In each instance I change seeds, RPC address and listen to the address of external IP of the nodes in cassandra.yaml file.
In cassandra-env.sh I un commented the line-
JVM_OPTS = "JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x" to external ip of instance.
I am still running into the following error when i try to run the nodes and check their status-

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

Comment: when you updated the configuration, did you restarted the nodes (preferably one at a time)? Also, is the cluster up and healthy? (you can verify this with `nodetool status`

Comment: Yes, I stopped the nodes, deleted data files, changed config file and then restarted node. And then I can't get the cluster working and run into above errors.